# What does Hashem see right now?

Tags: theology

I know Hashem looks down at us and watches everything we do. The question I am trying to ask is, what does he see right now? I don't think Hashem exists in time, as he is not in the past or the future. So right now, does he see Avraham doing what he did (like killing that lamb 2000 years ago), does he see me writing this question, or does he see everything at once?

Comment: Carrot that is one theory supported by a Gemara where hashem Talks about the Story of Piligesh Bgivah.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question was closed. I believe there is enough written on the subject to make it legitimate. I would ask Carrot monster to reword it, but I think it could be constructive.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed)

- Hashem doesn't "see" like we see with our eyes. Hashem "seeing" refers to what his attention is turned to (and his attention turns to Tzadikim, meaning he directly watches over them).
- The Rambam has some interesting things to say about what Hashem directly controls in our world. For instance Hashem doesn't directly watch over each individual non-human animal, non-jew and am-haaretz, only Tzadikim, but he does involve himself with each animal species. Also, Hashem has natural-laws like gravity, so He doesn't need to watch over each leaf falling.
- How does Hashem experience time? He doesn't experience time like we do. He is outside time, unchanging and infinite. Past, future, present, it's all illogical to apply to God. As for us, what's in the past happened, there's no changing it. Men made their choices, and history is locked into place because of their decisions. Hashem isn't presently looking at a "present" 2000 years ago, that happened already. What's in the future is not determined, as man hasn't imposed his will on it yet. That being said, Hashem can know the future as He is outside time and God can view it as having already happened, but it doesn't effect your free will in the present.

Comment: Do you have any sources?

Comment: @zaq I like your answer. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

well hashem see your past and can see yor future but still gives free will of choice
good q lee

Comment: kimbo, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the quick answer! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 0):

Hashem isn't in time he is beyond time and the part about free will is that he give syou chose if there was no free will he would never have given a choice at all bc he would know what they would do already.